# Send Angular Value to another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my app, I have a menu that routes content via ID but I also have a detailed view where the content should be displayed (via the same ID).

I'm trying to display objects by their ID via button click and I'm not sure how I could pass the ID value to the item-detail component for it to display the content by ID.
All the data I need is made available in a service.

I already route via ID and this works fine

```
path: ':id',
component: ItemDetailComponent,
data:
{
    title: 'Item Detail',
}
```

**item.component.html** (menu component)

Here I trigger an event

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <button (click)="getId(item.id);"></button>
```

**item.component.ts** (menu component)

Here I get the id of the object

```
getId(datavalue: number) 
{
      console.log(datavalue); 
}
```

When I click on the button I get the correct ID in my console log.

Now I want to display the content in the detailed view by ID but I'm not sure how I could pass the ID to this component.

**item-detail.component.html**
Maybe something like this?

```
<div>
    <h2>Text Content</h2>
    <p>
        {{glossar[datavalue]?.textContent}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: there are some ways to achieve this like: 1.) use @output and event emitter 2.) send it via rxjs using subject/behaviorSubject.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, so you should pass the ID to the item-detail component as @Input() parameter for the component, something like this:

```
 @Input()
 id: number;
```

HTML:

```
<item-detail-component [id]="item.id"></item-detail-component>
```

And then inside the item-detail-component load data via that id to get there details.

Comment: and sure, the best way to understand that behaivor is look at angular.io pages

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the routing module, then you should use the routing.

```
<button [routerLink]="[item.id]" (click)="getId(item.id);"></button>
```

If you have correctly set up your routing with router outlets and correct routes, this should work.

In your component, use the activated route to get your ID

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { this.id = route.snapshot.params.id; }
```

Comment: { this.id = route.snapshot.params.id; } it tells me that property 'id' is not available

Comment: Did you declare `id` as a variable of your component  ?